# node model to upload files and retrieve files on gitlab

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, gitlab, github-api

I have a web application. I want user could upload files to gitlab from my Application. I have done the same thing for GitHub using octokat node model  but I am unable to find it for gitlab . please help me.